# viewWillAppear not getting called on UIPageViewController child

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

So I have UIPageViewController and on it 2 UIViewControllers. I want to know when each of them is being shown, but viewWillAppear or didAppear are not called when they are switched. Does anyone have any idea why not or how to know when are they swiped apart from checking swipe in UIPageViewController?

```
class HomePageViewController: UIPageViewController {

weak var homePageDelegate: HomePageViewControllerDelegate?

var sequenceControl: PageContainerViewController!
var chatControl: PageContainerViewController!
var directControl: PageContainerViewController!
var lastShownControl: PageContainerViewController!

private var partnerConnectionChanged = true

private(set) lazy var soloViewControllers: Array<UIViewController> = {
    return loadViews(for: .solo)
}()

private(set) lazy var partnerViewControllers: Array<UIViewController> = {
    return loadViews(for: .partner)
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = self
    delegate = self

    WebSocketController.sharedInstance.add(self)

    prepareViews()

    if let initialViewController = getViewsList().first {
        scrollToViewController(viewController: initialViewController)
    }

    homePageDelegate?.homePageViewController(homePageViewController: self, didUpdatePageCount: getViewsList().count)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (FlowController.sharedInstance.showDeviceConnect) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    }
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}

func prepareViews(){
    sequenceControl = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageContainerIdentifier") as? PageContainerViewController
    sequenceControl.setViewOption(to: .sequenceView, with: self)
    chatControl = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageContainerIdentifier") as? PageContainerViewController
    chatControl.setViewOption(to: .chatView, with: self)
    directControl = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageContainerIdentifier") as? PageContainerViewController
    directControl.setViewOption(to: .directControlView, with: self)
}

func loadViews(for arrayType: ArrayType) -> Array<UIViewController>{
    var viewContainers = Array<UIViewController>()
    viewContainers.append(sequenceControl)
    if(arrayType == .partner){
        viewContainers.append(chatControl)
    }
    viewContainers.append(directControl)
    return viewContainers
}

func getViewsList() -> [UIViewController]{
    if (WebSocketController.sharedInstance.partnerConnected) {
        return partnerViewControllers
    } else {
        return soloViewControllers
    }
}

 //MARK: - Page Controller

/**
 Scrolls to the next view controller.
 */
public func scrollToNextViewController() {
    if let visibleViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let nextViewController = pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: visibleViewController) {
        scrollToViewController(viewController: nextViewController)
    }
}

/**
 Scrolls to the previous view controller.
 */
public func scrollToPreviousViewController() {
    if let visibleViewController = viewControllers?.last,
        let previousViewController = pageViewController(self, viewControllerBefore: visibleViewController) {
        scrollToViewController(viewController: previousViewController, direction: .reverse)
    }
}

/**
 Scrolls to the view controller at the given index. Automatically calculates
 the direction.

 - parameter newIndex: the new index to scroll to
 */
func scrollToViewController(index newIndex: Int) {
    if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let currentIndex = getViewsList().index(of:firstViewController) {
        let direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = newIndex >= currentIndex ? .forward : .reverse
        let nextViewController = getViewsList()[newIndex]
        scrollToViewController(viewController:nextViewController, direction: direction)
    }
}

/**
 Scrolls to the given 'viewController' page.

 - parameter viewController: the view controller to show.
 */
private func scrollToViewController(viewController: UIViewController,
                                    direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = .forward) {
    setViewControllers([viewController],
                       direction: direction,
                       animated: true,
                       completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                        // Setting the view controller programmatically does not fire
                        // any delegate methods, so we have to manually notify the
                        // 'tutorialDelegate' of the new index.
                        self.notifyHomePageDelegateOfNewIndex()
                        self.lastShownControl = viewController as? PageContainerViewController
                        self.showTutorial()
    })
}

/**
 Notifies '_tutorialDelegate' that the current page index was updated.
 */
private func notifyHomePageDelegateOfNewIndex() {
    if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let index = getViewsList().index(of:firstViewController) {
        homePageDelegate?.homePageViewController(homePageViewController: self, didUpdatePageIndex: index)
    }
}
}

// MARK: UIPageViewControllerDataSource

extension  HomePageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = getViewsList().index(of:viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    // User is on the first view controller and swiped left to loop to
    // the last view controller.
    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    guard getViewsList().count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return getViewsList()[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = getViewsList().index(of:viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let listViewControllersCount = getViewsList().count

    // User is on the last view controller and swiped right to loop to
    // the first view controller.
    guard listViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    guard listViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return getViewsList()[nextIndex]
}

//MARK: - WebSocket Delegat

func connectionPartnerChanged(success: Bool) {
    partnerConnectionChanged = true
}
}

extension  HomePageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
                        previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
                        transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    notifyHomePageDelegateOfNewIndex()
}

}

protocol  HomePageViewControllerDelegate: class {

/**
 Called when the number of pages is updated.

 - parameter homePageViewController: the TutorialPageViewController instance
 - parameter count: the total number of pages.
 */
func homePageViewController(homePageViewController:  HomePageViewController,
                            didUpdatePageCount count: Int)

/**
 Called when the current index is updated.

 - parameter homePageViewController: the TutorialPageViewController instance
 - parameter index: the index of the currently visible page.
 */
func homePageViewController(homePageViewController:  HomePageViewController,
                            didUpdatePageIndex index: Int)
}
```

Comment: Hmmm? Quick test, both `viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()` are triggered when swiping (scrolling) between view controllers in a `UIPageViewController`. Are you sure you're putting the code in the right place?

Comment: I don't know why but mine are not called, since I tested it with debugging. I added my UIPageViewController code so that you can tell me if you find any mistake.

Comment: The ```viewWillAppear``` is never called or it's called once, I think it is called at least one time.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` called every time when you navigate or come back to the  same screen.In your case `UIPageViewController` is like `rootViewController`, it is not navigating while swipe but your `UIViewController` is navigating.

Comment: @danypata It is called the first time it is shown, but after that when I swipe it is never called.

Comment: That's because you never recreate the controller, you store your controllers in array and return them whenever you need, and since you have only 2 controllers in the page view controller, the page view controller doesn't have to remove them at all so that's why you do not get multiple calls of viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear. You can check my previous answer for a simple implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52432013/2315974

Comment: @schmru check my answer

Comment: @SaurabhJain I did and it helped me to solve my problem, so thanks for help

Comment: @schmru If it is helpful for you, then give it to correct answer, so it help to others :)

Answer (score 4):

Use this `UIPageViewController Delegate method` :

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
            willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    let controller = pendingViewControllers?.first as? SecondViewController
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
          didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, 
     previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], 
         transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if completed {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are called for the View Controller that is ***appearing***.

So, you need to implement those funcs *inside the "page" view controllers* ... **not** inside the `UIPageViewController` itself.

If you need the `UIPageViewController` to know about it, either implement the `willTransitionTo` and `didFinishAnimating` UIPageViewController Delegate methods, or create your own protocol / delegate functions.

Comment: I did add `viewDidAppear` in the `UIViewController` but sometimes it did not get called. Especially when you are swiping between pages.

Comment: I had to implement a protocol to conform to so that I could call a method on the detail VCs using the UIPageViewControllerDelegate methods. That gives you the hook to know a VC is now visible so that the VC could refresh its status. NOTE: The `pageVIewController:willTransitionTo:` method can be canceled if the user swipes the other way, so you'll want to check the `completed` flag in `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:completed` to make sure it actually transitioned (otherwise the active view may be a previousVC).